# Spring Thymeleaf not loading CSS (xml configuration)

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am building a Spring web application with thymeleaf. I made the configurations based on xml and everything works except css resource reference. I am using spring version **5.0.1.RELEASE** and thymeleaf version **3.0.1.RELEASE**.

The login page is working but the css does not load. I think the problem is from the configurations.

Here is the project layout:

```
Spring
|- src/main/java/
|  |- com.web
|  |
|- WebContent
|  |- META-INF
|  |
|  |- WEB-INF
|     |- WEB-INF
|        |- lib
|        |- resources
|           |- css
|              |- style.css
|           |- views
|              |- login
|                 |- login.html
|        |- web.xml
|        |- applicationConfig-mvc.xml
|        |- applicationContext.xml
```

My **web.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My **applicationContext.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="applicationConfig-mvc.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web" />

</beans>
```

And my **applicationConfig-mvx.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/css/" mapping="/resources/css/**" />
    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/resources/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="*" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Login.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Login page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css"
    th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login page</h1>
    <p th:if="${loginError}" class="error">Wrong user or password</p>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>:
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <br />
        <label for="password">Password</label>:
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </form>
    <p>
        <a href="../index.html" th:href="@{/}">Back to home page</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you any comments on the structure, configurations or naming, please help me because I am learning how to do it right now. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps putting a type would help? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" type="text/css" th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" />`

Comment: No, this not working. I think the problem is from the configurations where I am declaring resource mapping in applicationConfig-mvx.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem in the beginning :)

Put your css, js, images, ... inside a "static" folder within the resources directory. Otherwise thymeleaf can't find it.
It should look like this: resources -> static -> css -> style.css
You can now access the css via href="css/style.css"
The same goes for js, images, etc.

EDIT: Added pictures of a sample project

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuuZc.png)

[Html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruv8U.png)

Check out the demo project under [Github](https://github.com/Viergelenker/ThymeleafCssDemo) ! :)

Comment: Can you tell me what must be in the configuration file for `<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />` and what will be the href in the html. Something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"
 th:href="@{/resources/static/css/style.css}" />` ? Thank you

Comment: You don't need to specify the location with my suggested configuration. You can either use th:href=... or href=... Using both doesn't make sense in my eyes.

Comment: Please see the edit of my original answer. I added images of my project structure and a sample html file. I tested it and it works on my setup. Try to specify your stylesheet only with href="css/style.css" (remove the th:href="...") and see if that works. If not, tell me and we will find another solution. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much. You are perfect, really! I found another solution if the project is Dynamic Web Project and if you are using WebContent and WEB-INF, the resource directory should be in the root on the WebContent dir and in the html `<link th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />`

So the project structure is:

`WebContent
      META-INF
      WEB-INF
                  templates/*
      resources
                  css/*
`